# How to translate a part of string in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

I am a beginner on Aurelia. I have the following code and I want to localize(translate) "Jahre" word to english/german language when we select one of them.

```html
<option repeat.for="interval of intervals">${interval}&nbsp Jahre</option>
```

How can I localize this part of sentence?
If I want to localize a word or the whole sentence, I don't have any problem. I have just problem, when I want to localize a part of a sentence.
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way would be localising the whole sentence with parameters. Like this:

```js
// Translation file
{
  "years": "{{count}} Jahre"
}

// Translation file
{
  "years": "{{count}} years"
}
```

Then, you can use pass the parameters via `t-params`:

```html
<p t="years" t-params.bind="myVariable"></span> //myVariable = { count: 5 }
```

Or

```html
<p>${ 'years' | t: { count: 5 } }</p>
```

More information at: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/i18n/latest/i18n-with-aurelia/5

Comment: I does not work. please pay attention: I have a repeat.for in the code

Comment: Having a `repeat.for` makes no difference... Have you tried this `<option repeat.for="interval of intervals">${ 'years' | t: { count: interval } }</option>` ?. Are you sure you've configured the i18n plugin correctly?

Comment: It doesn't work. Another words are translated correctly, the problem is in repeat.for

Comment: I solved it. Thank you for your help. It was useful.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved it:

```
// json file
"tests": {
 "title": "Tests",
 "reminders": {
   "years_singular": "{{count}} Year",
   "years_plural": "{{count}} Years"
}
// html file
<select class="select-interval" value.bind="capacityTestInterval">
      <option repeat.for="interval of intervals"
              model.bind="interval"
              t="tests.reminders.years"
              t-params.bind="{count: interval, context: interval === 1 ? 'singular' : 'plural' }">
      </option>
</select>
```

Thank [Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1148153/fabio-luz) for your help

Comment: this is pretty much what I said my answer... anyway, glad it worked!

Comment: You don't need to treat plural as context. Your translation keys can be `years` and `years_plural` and your t-params just `{count: interval}`